# Listeners: using variable to track when to perform function vs adding and removing listeners?

Tags: events

If you are tracking events are there any benefits or drawbacks to constantly adding and removing listeners vs tracking when to act based on an event using a variable?

It seems that most examples use the second approach but wondered about the first and it seems to work fine for me.

```
    function mouse(element) {
        function mouse_start(event) { 
            if (event.buttons!=1) return;
            event.preventDefault();
            element.addEventListener('mousemove', mouse_move); 
        }
        function mouse_end(event) {
            element.removeEventListener('mousemove', mouse_move);
        }
        function mouse_move(event){
            console.log(event.movementX, event.movementY);
        }
        element.addEventListener('mousedown', mouse_start);
        element.addEventListener('mouseup',   mouse_end);
    }
```

```
    function mouse(element) {
        var mouse_started = false;
        function mouse_start(event) { 
            if (event.buttons!=1) return;
            event.preventDefault();
            mouse_started = true;
        }
        function mouse_end(event) {
            mouse_started = false;
        }
        function mouse_move(event){
            if (!mouse_started) return;
            console.log(event.movementX, event.movementY);
        }
        element.addEventListener('mousedown', mouse_start);
        element.addEventListener('mouseup',   mouse_end);
        element.addEventListener('mousemove', mouse_move);
    }
```